# How to get find and get URL in a NSString in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, http, url, nsstring

I have a text with http:// in NSString. I want to get that http link from the NSString. How can i get the link/url from the string? Eg: 'Stack over flow is very useful link for the beginners  https://stackoverflow.com/'. I want to get the 'https://stackoverflow.com/' from the text. How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly mean by link but if you want to convert your NSString to NSURL than you can do the following:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://somepage.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

**EDIT**

This is how to get all URLs in a given NSString:

```
NSString *str = @"This is a grate website http://xxx.xxx/xxx you must check it out"; 

NSArray *arrString = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for(int i=0; i<arrString.count;i++){
    if([[arrString objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound)
        NSLog(@"%@", [arrString objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: A bit longwinded to split it into an array and then search the substrings for the range, when you can just search for the substring's range in the first place, just once.

Comment: @Abizern The substring you are referring would only work for one case and that is if there would only be one URL in the string and if that URL would be the last object in the string, it would not work if the URL would be hidden in the middle of a text, and it would not work for multiple URL's

Comment: Yeah, with the extended question he asked, it would seem your solution fits the bill better. However, a block based enumeration and checking against [[arrString objectAtIndex:i] hasPrefix:@"http://"]; might be a bit more performant.

Comment: I know its a little bit late , but this answer is great !!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than splitting the string into an array and messing about that way, you can just search for the substring beginning with @"http://":

```
NSString *str = @"Stack over flow is very useful link for the beginners http://stackoverflow.com/";
// get the range of the substring starting with @"http://"
NSRange rng = [str rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

// Set up the NSURL variable to hold the created URL
NSURL *newURL = nil;

// Make sure that we actually have found the substring
if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"URL not found");
    // newURL is initialised to nil already so nothing more to do.
} else {
    // Get the substring from the start of the found substring to the end.
    NSString *urlString = [str substringFromIndex:rng.location];

    // Turn the string into an URL and put it into the declared variable
    newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I have one more doubt on this How can i get the link from this text 'Stack over flow is very useful link for the http://stackoverflow.com/ beginners'? Thanks.

Comment: That's a completely different question!

Comment: Thanks. Mr.Cyprian answer works for me very fine. Thanks for your effort. Once again i thank you and i upvote your answer.

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M As you wish, but using a scanner or a regular expression would be more efficient. But if you aren't using this method a lot it is unlikely to make a difference to your code execution.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
nsstring *str = @"Stack over flow is very useful link for the beginners http://stackoverflow.com/";

nsstring *http = @"http";
nsarray *arrURL = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"http"];
```

this will give two objects in the nsarray. 1st object will be having:`Stack over flow is very useful link for the beginners` and 2nd will be : `://stackoverflow.com/` (i guess)

then you can do like:

```
  NSString *u = [arrURL lastObject];
```

then do like:

```
nsstring *http = [http stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",u];
```

Quite a lengthy,but i think that would work for you. Hope that helps you.